# Git CI/CD Pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner

I am running simple Gitpipeline, My yaml file contains opening the notepad application

```
stages:      
    # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - build
  
run_batch_script:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - draw-w11-test
  script:
    - Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
```

This script works fine when run on the runner configured machine, But when run through the CI/CD pipeline, Doesn't open the application

Was trying Git CI?CD, Expected it to open the notepad application

Comment: I have  also observed that when this pipeline runs, Notepad++ application is seen in the Background Process under Task Manager

Comment: Are you running the runner as a service? If so, you'll have to edit the service and allow it to interact with the desktop (on the Log On tab of the service's properties), and you might have to start the runner as your user account too (like running the runner from a powershell console instead of from the services)- not sure.

Comment: Tried running the service- Allow interact option - didn't work , Also started the runner service from powershell- didn't work

Comment: Can you add more detail to your question?